# setFormFieldName() on a non-object magento Admin

Tags: php, magento

On manage product page, I'm getting no grid, I traced it and it shows the error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setFormFieldName() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php on line 279

I don't know whats wrong with it.

Comment: Well the error speaks for itself : the script is trying to call a method named "setFormFieldName()" on something that does not have such a method :)  Could you display us line 279 please ?

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/tyjUFX67 here is the line  $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('product');

Comment: @harry $this->getMassactionBlock() is null

Comment: got the error, there was some other plugin malfunctioning

Answer (score 0):

I think the FieldName value is invalid, it should be $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('product_id');